# Xamarin Pillar navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation

What is the correct way to handle model navigation?

The first case below works as expected but I can then go back to the login page which I don't want.  The second case I can see in the debugger that that page is loaded but never shown.  Basically the model page stays on top.  I am thinking I need to either close the model page before changing pages or I need to handle this differently.  I don't won't to pop to root because the root is no longer home but main.

What I really won't to do is change the root, how?

[Edit] This seems to help but there is still a flicker when I unload the modal page.
    await _navigator.PushAsync(vm => { vm.NoHistory = true; });

Case 1:

```
return viewFactory.Resolve<HomeVM>(); - from APP.cs
await _navigator.PushAsync<LoginVM>();
await _navigator.PushAsync<MainVM>();
```

Case 2:

```
return viewFactory.Resolve<HomeVM>(); - from APP.cs
await _navigator.PushModalAsync<LoginVM>();
await _navigator.PushAsync<MainVM>();  - Never works.
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to reset MainPage completely with the new page when login in successfully.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authLoginToken))

            MainPage = new LoginPage();

        else

            MainPage = new RootPage();
```

More detailed info, you can take a look the following thread:

https://github.com/asthanarht/CPXamarin/blob/master/CPMobile/CPMobile/App.cs

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48634/from-login-page-to-main-page

Comment: Yes, I started that way  but then starting using askaiser.mobile.pillar which was why the question.  I many have to abandon pillar and switch back to manual, that first link looks good.